# Best way to choose a random file from a directory in a shell script

Tags: bash, file, shell, random

What is the best way to choose a random file from a directory in a shell script?

Here is my solution in Bash but I would be very interested for a more portable (non-GNU) version for use on Unix proper.

```
dir='some/directory'
file=`/bin/ls -1 "$dir" | sort --random-sort | head -1`
path=`readlink --canonicalize "$dir/$file"` # Converts to full path
echo "The randomly-selected file is: $path"
```

Anybody have any other ideas?

**Edit:** lhunath makes a good point about parsing `ls`.  I guess it comes down to whether you want to be portable or not.  If you have the GNU findutils and coreutils then you can do:

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 \
  | sort --zero-terminated --random-sort \
  | sed 's/\d000.*//g/'
```

Whew, that was fun!  Also it matches my question better since I said "random file".  Honsetly though, these days it's hard to imagine a Unix system deployed out there having GNU installed but not Perl 5.

Comment: The bash way would use $(...) instead of `...`.

Comment: Good point.  I was a bit unclear.  In practice, I'm using Bash on Linux, but in theory it'd be cool if it runs on sh on Unix, which means backticks and no GNU coreutils.

Comment: @JasonSmith `$(…)` is in POSIX. If you still have a shell that doesn't support it, put `/usr/xpg4/bin` or something like that in front of `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`, and call `/usr/bin/env sh` rather than `/bin/sh`. (Or else you're running a real antique.)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
files=(/my/dir/*)
printf "%s\n" "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
```

And **don't parse ls**.  Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Edit: Good luck finding a non-`bash` solution that's reliable.  Most will break for certain types of filenames, such as filenames with spaces or newlines or dashes (it's pretty much impossible in pure `sh`).  To do it right without `bash`, you'd need to fully migrate to `awk`/`perl`/`python`/... without piping that output for further processing or such.

Comment: RANDOM and arrays are Bash features, and the OP is "interested [in] a more portable (non-GNU) version for use on Unix proper".

Comment: Thanks @lhunath, The point about ls is well-taken.  I updated the question.

Comment: your example doesn't actually work, `printf "%s\n" "${files[RANDOM % ${#files}]}"` should be `printf "%s\n" "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"` -- `${#files}` represents the length (strlen) of the first value in the `files` array. `${#files[@]}` represents the number of elements in the `files` array, which is what we want.

Comment: It's not much more difficult to handle arbitrary file names in portable sh than in bash. The only thing in bash that makes it easier is arrays, and that's only useful when you need to manipulate multiple lists of file names at the same time.

Comment: Note that `printf` isn't part of the solution, unless you want the filename on stdout instead of as an arg to an arbitrary command.

Comment: If I understood your link correctly, parsing `ls` is only a problem if there are files containing newlines in them. In a lot of cases people can know for certain that the files in the directory they are parsing won't contain any of such files. Parsing `ls` is especially easy if you want to do stuff right on the command line instead of writing a script.

Comment: @Rapti no, parsing `ls` is always harder than not parsing `ls`.  `$(ls)` is much harder than `*` and it causes bugs.  There is no excuse for parsing `ls`.  `ls` is a tool for humans, not for code.  Every time you parse `ls` you're adding a potential for bugs at the same time as making life harder on yourself.  All you need to do is learn what globs are, and you will never need `ls` again.

Answer (score 35):

Is "shuf" not portable?

```
shuf -n1 -e /path/to/files/*
```

or find if files are deeper than one directory:

```
find /path/to/files/ -type f | shuf -n1
```

it's part of coreutils but you'll need 6.4 or newer to get it... so RH/CentOS does not include it.

Comment: Really useful for people who need something to just work. Doesn't matter who, doesn't matter *how* hacky it is.

Comment: You can use gshuf (`brew install gshuf`) on Mac. Works with Mavericks for sure but not tested on any other versions!

Comment: `shuf` is now in the `coreutils` formula, and is prefixed with g (type `gshuf` after installing the `coreutils` formula)

Comment: `brew install gshuf` didn't work for me, but `brew install coreutils` did.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
let x="$RANDOM % ${#file}"
echo "The randomly-selected file is ${path[$x]}"
```

`$RANDOM` in bash is a special variable that returns a random number, then I use modulus division to get a valid index, then reference that index in the array.

Comment: Poster want's a solution with no Bash-isms.

Comment: @MGoDave don't feel too bad.  I am always interested in a good Bash solution and a good GNU-free solution, for different situations and as a mental exercise.

Comment: And #file is what exactly?

Comment: @harperville `${#file}` is the number of elements in the bash array `file`

Answer (score 4):

```
# ******************************************************************
# ******************************************************************
function randomFile {
  tmpFile=$(mktemp)

  files=$(find . -type f > $tmpFile)
  total=$(cat "$tmpFile"|wc -l)
  randomNumber=$(($RANDOM%$total))

  i=0
  while read line;  do
    if [ "$i" -eq "$randomNumber" ];then
      # Do stuff with file
      amarok $line
      break
    fi
    i=$[$i+1]
  done < $tmpFile
  rm $tmpFile
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to post a little explanation along with the code.

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to: How can I create a random number in a Unix script in a portable way?

Because if you have a random number between 1 and N, you can use `head -$N | tail` to cut somewhere in the middle. Unfortunately, I know no portable way to do this with the shell alone. If you have Python or Perl, you can easily use their random support but AFAIK, there is no standard `rand(1)` command.

Comment: That's a good point.  Is `ls -1` standard on Unix, or is that just GNU? Anyway yes the biggest problem is getting a random number.  I would argue that Perl is pretty universal since it's been shipping standard since IIRC Solaris 2.6 and HP-UX 11i

Comment: -1 as an argument to ls is standard in SUS2 (http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/ls.html).  I don't know when it was added, but I believe it was available back in the POSIX days as well.

Comment: @Chas thanks for the link.  Still, Aaron has a point that filenames with newlines could cause problems.  So that could be relevent depending on whether and how you let "civilians" create files directly on the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I think Awk is a good tool to get a random number.  According to the [Advanced Bash Guide](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/randomvar.html), Awk is a good random number replacement for `$RANDOM`.

Here's a version of your script that avoids Bash-isms and GNU tools.

```
#! /bin/sh

dir='some/directory'
n_files=`/bin/ls -1 "$dir" | wc -l | cut -f1`
rand_num=`awk "BEGIN{srand();print int($n_files * rand()) + 1;}"`
file=`/bin/ls -1 "$dir" | sed -ne "${rand_num}p"`
path=`cd $dir && echo "$PWD/$file"` # Converts to full path.  
echo "The randomly-selected file is: $path"
```

It inherits the problems other answers have mentioned should files contain newlines.

Comment: That's a great idea.  You have to scan the directory twice and there is a race condition if the number of files changes in between scans, but in practice that's probably not a big deal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm convinced that traditional Bourne shell programming is fundamentally flawed for many situations regardless of one's best efforts.  Enter Bash and GNU coreutils to save the day.

Comment: Awk does get you a random number, and it's the only way offered by POSIX, but it's a very bad RNG (predictable, and the output only changes once per second). Also, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

Newlines in file-names can be avoided by doing the following in Bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

DIR="/home/user"

for file in $(ls -1 $DIR)
do
    echo $file
done

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shell snippet that relies only on POSIX features and copes with arbitrary file names (but omits dot files from the selection). The random selection uses awk, because that's all you get in POSIX. It's a very poor random number generator, since awk's RNG is seeded with the current time in seconds (so it's easily predictable, and returns the same choice if you call it multiple times per second).

```
set -- *
n=$(echo $# | awk '{srand(); print int(rand()*$0) + 1}')
eval "file=\$$n"
echo "Processing $file"
```

If you don't want to ignore dot files, the file name generation code (`set -- *`) needs to be replaced by something more complicated.

```
set -- *; [ -e "$1" ] || shift
set .[!.]* "$@"; [ -e "$1" ] || shift
set ..?* "$@"; [ -e "$1" ] || shift
if [ $# -eq 0]; then echo 1>&2 "empty directory"; exit 1; fi
```

If you have OpenSSL available, you can use it to generate random bytes. If you don't but your system has `/dev/urandom`, replace the call to `openssl` by `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=3 count=1 2>/dev/null`. Here's a snippet that sets `n` to a random value between 1 and `$#`, taking care not to introduce a bias. This snippet assumes that `$#` is at most 2^23-1.

```
while
  n=$(($(openssl rand 3 | od -An -t u4) + 1))
  [ $n -gt $((16777216 / $# * $#)) ]
do :; done
n=$((n % $#))
```

Answer (score 1):

BusyBox (used on embedded devices) is usually configured to support `$RANDOM` but it doesn't have bash-style arrays or `sort --random-sort` or `shuf`. Hence the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES="/usr/bin/*"
for f in $FILES; do  echo "$RANDOM $f" ; done | sort -n | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Note trailing "-" in `cut -f2-`; this is required to avoid truncating files that contain spaces (or whatever separator you want to use).

It won't handle filenames with embedded newlines correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Put each line of output from the command 'ls' into an associative array named line and then choose one of those like so...

```
ls | awk '{ line[NR]=$0 } END { print line[(int(rand()*NR+1))]}'
```

Comment: The first set of curly braces { line[NR]=$0 } , creates an associative array arbitrarily named 'line' that stores each line of output from ls, indexed by NR, which is a special awk variable that indicates the number of the record.

After all lines of output have been stored in the array, awk moves on to the  END section. NR at this point equals the total number of lines of output from ls. So, we pick a random number from NR and retrieve the line at that index. 

To better answer OP's question ls could be replaced by 'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f'

Comment: In an environment restricted to just Unix Shell this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents, with a version that should not break when filenames with special chars exist:

```
#!/bin/bash --
dir='some/directory'

let number_of_files=$(find "${dir}" -type f -print0 | grep -zc .)
let rand_index=$((1+(RANDOM % number_of_files)))

printf "the randomly-selected file is: "
find "${dir}" -type f -print0 | head -z -n "${rand_index}" | tail -z -n 1
printf "\n"
```

Comment: Single quotes aren't needed around the dir. Apart from that this works a treat!