# Select randomly a file from various directories and sort

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a lot of text files spread out across several directories. I would like to sort all files and create a list of file names (in a text file) but in a peculiar and defined order. My initial thoughts are to randomly select the first file `*1.txt` from those directories. Then repeat the process (`*2.txt, *3.txt, etc.`) till all files names are in the list. How can I accomplish this in bash?

**The basics:**

Randomly selects file from 1 directory:

```
shuf -n1 –e *
```

Selects the first file from 1 directory:

```
ls | sort -n | head -1
```

EXAMPLE:

**UPDATED: file strucutre / real file names format**(this is just a few of the files, there are a few hundreds)

Initial order:

```
media/sf_linux_sandbox/papers/
|-- semester_1
|   |-- cs630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
|   |-- cs635-progamming_languages-fname_lname-002.txt
|   |-- cs645-java_programming_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
|   `-- cs900-computer_robotics_capstone-fname_lname-004.txt
|-- semester_2
|   |-- cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
|   |-- cs675-nosql_db_research-fname_lname-002.txt
|   |-- cs700-artificial_intelligence_reasearch-fname_lname-003.txt
|   |-- cs800-algorithms_and_computational_complexity-fname_lname-004.txt
|   |-- cs825-database_systems_internals-fname_lname-005.txt
|   `-- cs850-computer_graphics-fname_lname-006.txt
|-- semester_3
    |-- cs725-web_programming_technologies-fname_lname-001.txt
    |-- cs750-data_programming-fname_lname-002.txt
    `-- cs775-hardware_software_interface_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
```

The output/result I am looking to generate(Randomly shuffle the files but keep the numerical order):

```
results.txt
/filepath/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/s630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs725-web_programming_technologies-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs635-progamming_languages-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs750-data_programming-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs675-nosql_db_research-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs645-java_programming_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs775-hardware_software_interface_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs700-artificial_intelligence_reasearch-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs900-computer_robotics_capstone-fname_lname-004.txt
/filepath/cs800-algorithms_and_computational_complexity-fname_lname-004.txt
/filepath/cs825-database_systems_internals-fname_lname-005.txt
/filepath/cs850-computer_graphics-fname_lname-006.txt
```

Comment: You would probably have to store the results of a `find -type d` or something similar in an array. Then find the largest number of regular files in any directory in your array, use that as the max bound in a `((i=1; i<=max; i++))` loop, shuffle the array in each body of the loop, and then traverse it copying the `$i'th` file in each directory if it exists, and nothing if it doesn't (i.e. if the directory has less than `$i` files). Might be a simpler way, but not one I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Sweet, I kinda follow you. Could you please show me an example in answer format?

Comment: @BroSlow if you could show.

Comment: Why does the file move order matter to you? The order in which you add files to a directory does not generally relate to the iteration order (`ls`) afterwards...

Comment: @techAddict82 Sorry, a bit busy. I'll try to throw out a solution over the weekend if I have a moment and this hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: @BroSlow: Any idea on *why* the OP might want to do this? The only case I've encountered where the file creation order might matter is on an extremely simple MP3 player of mine, where the playlist was defined by the iteration order of the underlying FAT filesystem...

Comment: @thkala That seems like the most probable case, or he doesn't actually want to `move them`, but list or something else.

Comment: @thkala oh i thought the file order move to the `main` folder might have an impact in the final desired order. When I move the random file to the `main` folder i would like to append a number in this way i can numerically order the files. For example `c1-01.txt, b1-02.txt, d1-03.txt, etc`. Please suggest if there is a better way

Comment: @BroSlow alright i will wait for your answer

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Cyrus I would like to move those text files to the folder `main` and then sort. The sort is numerical but instead of `a1,b1,c1` i would like to be random `b1,c1,a1`.

Comment: The problem is the “sort” part:  Files inside a directory have no particular order provided by the file system.  Mathematically, a directory is a *set*, not a *vector*.  Given a particular file system implementation, you might get some reproducible ordering but it will be very brittle and not portable.  Maybe you just want a list of file names (in a text file)?

Comment: @5gon12eder the more I read into this the more I understand. You are correct. A listo file names in a text file

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer does what you want. Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shuffles all the files in the source tree, partially sorts on the numeric part with a stable sort, so the other elements remain shuffled.

```
$ target=~/tmp/shuf
$ destination=/filepath/
$ tree $target
~/tmp/shuf
`-- papers
    |-- semester_1
    |   |-- cs630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
    |   |-- cs635-progamming_languages-fname_lname-002.txt
    |   |-- cs645-java_programming_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
    |   `-- cs900-computer_robotics_capstone-fname_lname-004.txt
    |-- semester_2
    |   |-- cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
    |   |-- cs675-nosql_db_research-fname_lname-002.txt
    |   |-- cs700-artificial_intelligence_reasearch-fname_lname-003.txt
    |   |-- cs800-algorithms_and_computational_complexity-fname_lname-004.txt
    |   |-- cs825-database_systems_internals-fname_lname-005.txt
    |   `-- cs850-computer_graphics-fname_lname-006.txt
    `-- semester_3
        |-- cs725-web_programming_technologies-fname_lname-001.txt
        |-- cs750-data_programming-fname_lname-002.txt
        `-- cs775-hardware_software_interface_paper-fname_lname-003.txt

4 directories, 13 files
$ find $target -type f -iname "*.txt" \
   | shuf \
   | awk -F- '{printf("%s:%s\n", $0, $NF)}' \
   | sort -t : -k 2 -s \
   | cut -d : -f 1 \
   | xargs -n1 basename \
   | sed "s,^,$destination,"
/filepath/cs725-web_programming_technologies-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs635-progamming_languages-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs750-data_programming-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs675-nosql_db_research-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs775-hardware_software_interface_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs700-artificial_intelligence_reasearch-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs645-java_programming_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs900-computer_robotics_capstone-fname_lname-004.txt
/filepath/cs800-algorithms_and_computational_complexity-fname_lname-004.txt
/filepath/cs825-database_systems_internals-fname_lname-005.txt
/filepath/cs850-computer_graphics-fname_lname-006.txt
```

To store the result in a file called `filename`, you can redirect:

```
$ find $target -type f -iname "*.txt" \
   | shuf \
   | awk -F- '{printf("%s:%s\n", $0, $NF)}' \
   | sort -t : -k 2 -s \
   | cut -d : -f 1 \
   | xargs -n1 basename \
   | sed "s,^,$destination," \
   > filename
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for. I was not specific on what the files names look like therefore when i tested your answer i did not get the desired output. I have updated my question with the real file name format. Please check.

Comment: I've updated with the files you've provided. This will work with any number of files as long as the -###.txt part sorts correctly in lexical order. If this is not the case (as perhaps there are more than 1000 files in one directory, a little more work has to be done on the decoration for sort.

Comment: Could it include the full path to the files?

Comment: Target or destination?

Comment: Yes, the target. For example `media/sf_linux_sandbox/papers/semester_1/cs...`

Comment: I've update to match your example and desired output exactly. I'm not sure what you want when you say `semester_1/cs`. I've added a stab at that to the answer as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63310/discussion-between-chthonicdaemon-and-techaddict82).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I just wanted to include the absolute full file path.

Comment: Brilliant solution, +1.

Comment: A quick change I made: check chat

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be useful:

```
dir='some/directory'
file=`/bin/ls -1 "$dir" | sort --random-sort | head -1`
path=`readlink --canonicalize "$dir/$file"` # Converts to full path
echo "The randomly-selected file is: $path"
```

Consider have a look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701505/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory-in-a-shell-script).

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: I think he wants the first files (in numeric order) in each directory from a random directory ordering, second files in a directory ordering (not same as for first order), etc... In which case, this doesn't really answer the question. Though I could be wrong.

Comment: @BroSlow you are correct. This is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. Are you trying to sort numerically based on trailing digits in the filename? If so, you will need to supply exact specifications for your filenames so that a proper regex can be used to extract the digit and sort from there... I.e. are your filenames always [a-z][1-9] or are there multiple characters, special characters, etc? If you are able to supply the real paths you are using as well as the exact expected output then it would probably make things much easier.

To answer the question 'select randomly a file from various directories'...  Here are two very similar methods to display the path of one random file from each subdirectory of your current directory.

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | shuf -n1
done < <(find -type d) > results.txt
```

Or...

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in ./**/; do
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | shuf -n1
done > results.txt
shopt -u globstar
```

If you want the basename of each random file (rather than the full path), you can replace the inner `find` command with the following:

```
random="$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | shuf -n1)"
[[ -n $random ]] && echo "${random##*/}"
```

If you only want random txt files to be selected then just append the option `-name '*.txt'` to the end of the inner `find` command.

Note that I used the shuf command since you mentioned it in your question, but it probably could have been solved just as easily using $RANDOM.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to match the output that you provided in your post at the time I composed the answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage_exit () {
    echo "usage: $0 <target-directory>"
    exit 0
}

if [ $# != 1 ] ; then
    usage_exit
fi

# The pattern below searches files in the range 000 through 199.
# You can change the pattern to match your needs.
for n in {0..1}{0..9}{0..9}
    do find $1 -type f -name '*'$n'.txt' | shuf
done
```

Comment: `for i in {1..9}` what happens if I have hundreds of files?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, where you store the results of a find -type d in an array. Then find the largest number of regular files in any directory in your array, use that as the max bound in a `((i=1; i<=max; i++))` loop, shuffle the array in each body of the loop, and then traverse it copying the `$i'th` file in each directory if it exists, and nothing if it doesn't (i.e. if the directory has less than `$i` files).

```
#!/bin/bash

#shuffle function taken from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026
shuffle() {
   local i tmp size max rand

   # $RANDOM % (i+1) is biased because of the limited range of $RANDOM
   # Compensate by using a range which is a multiple of the array size.
   size=${#array[*]}
   max=$(( 32768 / size * size ))

   for ((i=size-1; i>0; i--)); do
      while (( (rand=$RANDOM) >= max )); do :; done
      rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))
      tmp=${array[i]} array[i]=${array[rand]} array[rand]=$tmp
   done
}

destination=/filepath
max=0
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r dir ; do
  array+=("$dir")
  count=$(ls -F "$dir" | egrep -v "^*[/*]$" | wc -l)
  ((count>max)) && max=$count
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)

for ((i=1; i<=max; i++)); do
  shuffle
  for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
    file=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' | sort -n | awk "NR==$i")
    [[ -n $file ]] && echo "$destination/$file" 
  done
done
```

Example

```
> tree
.
├── script
├── semester_1
│   ├── cs630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
│   ├── cs635-progamming_languages-fname_lname-002.txt
│   ├── cs645-java_programming_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
│   └── cs900-computer_robotics_capstone-fname_lname-004.txt
├── semester_2
│   ├── cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
│   ├── cs675-nosql_db_research-fname_lname-002.txt
│   ├── cs700-artificial_intelligence_reasearch-fname_lname-003.txt
│   ├── cs800-algorithms_and_computational_complexity-fname_lname-004.txt
│   ├── cs825-database_systems_internals-fname_lname-005.txt
│   └── cs850-computer_graphics-fname_lname-006.txt
└── semester_3
    ├── cs725-web_programming_technologies-fname_lname-001.txt
    ├── cs750-data_programming-fname_lname-002.txt
    └── cs775-hardware_software_interface_paper-fname_lname-003.txt

3 directories, 14 files
> ./script
/filepath/cs725-web_programming_technologies-fname_lname-001.txt 
/filepath/cs650-software_methodologies-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs630-linux_research_paper-fname_lname-001.txt
/filepath/cs750-data_programming-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs635-progamming_languages-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs675-nosql_db_research-fname_lname-002.txt
/filepath/cs645-java_programming_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs775-hardware_software_interface_paper-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs700-artificial_intelligence_reasearch-fname_lname-003.txt
/filepath/cs900-computer_robotics_capstone-fname_lname-004.txt
/filepath/cs800-algorithms_and_computational_complexity-fname_lname-004.txt
/filepath/cs825-database_systems_internals-fname_lname-005.txt
/filepath/cs850-computer_graphics-fname_lname-006.txt
```

Comment: Great, I just want to place the results in a text file but not move any actual files

Comment: Could i make this just do a random sort? Like no numerical order?

Comment: @techAddict82 Edited script slightly. Just change `sort -n` to whatever.

Comment: Great! but what do you mean by change `sort -n` to whatever?

Comment: Also `$dir` is the target directory for the sorting right? Sorry I am trying to get a full comprehension. I am liking this method.

Comment: @techAddict82 Depends on what order you want it in. `sort -n` will be numerical order, `sort` lexicographic. I think if you remove `sort` completely, native `ls` ordering should be lexicographic for most implementations as well. Yes, `$dir` is every directory in our current working directory (as returned by `find`, and saved in an array so we don't have to call it multiple times), and the target of the sorting.

Comment: Ran this but it is sorting all file types. I just want to sort the `.txt` files.

Comment: @techAddict82 Missed the part about only `*.txt` files, updated. Don't think you could modify the same algorithm I used to use `shuf` instead of some specific ordering, as it takes the 1st, 2nd, 3d, etc... file, so if the order is random you could always be taking the same file.

Comment: This technique seems to give more of a random result then the chosen answer

Comment: Made this a question. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581367/generate-a-random-list-of-all-txt-files-in-a-directory