# How can i add multiple audio randomly in one video using ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

```
(Number of audios in a folder )
[ audio1 , audio2 , audio3 , audio4 , audio5 ]
```

[ I have a Video ]
[ I want to merge these audios randomly with one video ]

For Example : after merging it should join random audio like this

```
Video 
audio3 + audio5 + audio2
```

Audios should not be repeated [should not happen like this ]

```
Video 
audio3 audio5 audio3
```

in this audio3 is repeated which is not allowed,
so repeated audios are not  allowed

ffmpeg code must be use here

(
code should work for any number of audios
like 20 to 50 audio randomly
)

audios should fit in a video size
(U are free to this in bash)
(If u do not understand the question , please let me know in the comment section )

Comment: Not possible with ffmpeg alone. You'll have to use shell scripting to provide the desired file order to ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan you are free to do in bash . you are most welcome .

Comment: There are already many questions and answers here that can help you get started such as [Best way to choose a random file from a directory in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701505/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory-in-a-shell-script) or search `[bash] random file`

Comment: @llogan i am already started and is doing as of now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a folder ./mp3/ (for example), and a video called video.mp4 you can do:

**1. Create a list of files**

```
for f in ./mp3/*.mp3; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

**2. (OPTION WITH PERL):** Order by rand this files but in txt (perl)

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<STDIN>);' < mylist.txt >> random.txt;
```

**2. (OPTION WITH BASH):** Order by rand this files but in txt (bash)

```
sort -Ru mylist.txt >> random.txt; done
```

**3. Create the unique audio file randomly**

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i random.txt -c copy output_rand.mp3
```

**4. Create a unique file with video and audio**

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a mp3 -i output_rand.mp3   -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a:0   -disposition:a:0 default   -disposition:a:1 default  -strict -2 -sn -dn -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1  -movflags faststart end_example.mp4
```

Regards

Comment: Look now on the Answer, I updated it with a bash simple code to dont use pearl, check it

sort -Ru mylist.txt >> random.txt; done